# how to train neural network with probabilistic input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, probability-density

Hello and thanks for helping,

My question is a long time problem that I try to tackle :

- How do we train a neural network if the input is a probability rather than a value ?

To make it more intuitive :

- Let's say we have 6 features and the value they may take is 1 or -1 for each.
- Their value is determined probabilistically, such as the feature 1 can be 1 with 60% probability or -1 with 30% probability.

How do we train the network if in each trial, we may get a INPUT value in accordance with the probability distribution of each feature ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer is more straingthforward than you might expect, as many existing neural networks are actually trained exactly in this manner. You have to do ... nothing. Simply sample your batch in each iteration according to your distribution and that's all. Neural network does not require finite training set, thus you can efficiently train it on "potentialy ifinite" one (generator of samples). This is exactly what is being done in image processing with image augmentation - each batch consists random subsamples of the images (patches), which are sampled from very basic probability distributions.

@Nagabuhushan suggests solving different problem - where you know a priori probability of each sample, which, according to question is not the case:

> we may get a INPUT value in accordance with the probability distribution of each feature

Plus, even if it would be the case, NNs are not good with multiplying thus one might need additional tweaking of architecture (log-transforms).

Answer (score 0):

For the values you feed into the net, you should use the probabilities of each feature taking on the value 1.  You could use the probabilities of them taking on -1, but be consistent.  Also, determine some order of features and consistently order their probabilities, respectively.

Edit: I think I may have misunderstood the question.  Do your inputs consist of probabilities, or 1's and -1's?  If the latter, then a well-architected network should learn the distributions on its own.  Just be sure to train it against the same input space that you'll be evaluating it against.

Comment: Thanks Dylon. Great answer. In line with your answer, I have one last question. So, lets say in trial 100, the input is generated as -1 with a probability of 30%, then I should input 0.6 (probability of 1) ? However, in this case, the training output should be probabilistic as well, like a probability distribution of 1 and -1 as the output. (60% chance of getting a 1 as input and let's say 50% chance of getting 1 as training output) Am I right ?

Comment: What is your goal with the network?  I don't think I understand what you want to do.  Also, if the probability of getting -1 is 30%, then the probability of getting a 1 is 100% - 30% = 70%, or 0.7 (but that's a technicality).

Comment: Are you treating the features as sequences of 1's and -1's, and trying to predict whether the next number will be 1 or -1?

Comment: Input consists of 1's or -1's, however it is generated probabilistically. So, in each trial we do not know the exact input but the probability of it. It may be 1 with let's say with 60% probability. However, it may be -1 with 30% probability as well. We need at least 100 trials, just to reveal the probability distribution of inputs.

Comment: The input sequence will be consisting of 1's or -1's generated with a probability. This problem is to model neural basis of decision making.

Comment: What do you want the network to do?  What should its output look like?

Comment: Network will be a classifier. One for all. Among 4 options, one will be chosen. However, options will have probabilistic inputs. So, training the network instance by instance is a mystery for me. One solution could be, after let's say 100 trials, we may have the actual probability distribution for the inputs . We already know the probability of outputs. So, maybe we can use these two, to train the network. Just a  guess...